# Get value from JsonResult response in another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I need get value from jsonresult response from controller to another controller

```
public ActionResult ToDo(){
...
 return Json(new { result = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult Caller(){
var response = ToDo;
if (response.Data.result == "success")
...
}
```

But don't work in this way

Comment: This shortened code is ridiculously unhelping in being able to understand the problem

Comment: @AviMeltser I must know json result and check it, but `if (response.Data.result == "success")` not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TempData` in MVC to pass the data from one controller to another.

In your first controller you can do something.

```
public ActionResult ToDo(){
...
 var result=new { result = "success" };
 TempData["jsonData"]=result ;
 return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then in you second controller you can get its value like:

```
public ActionResult Caller(){
var response = TempData["jsonData"];
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo finalresult =response.GetType().GetProperty("result");
string output = (string)(finalresult.GetValue(response, null));
if (output == "success")
...
}
```

Comment: it's works! Instead of `TempData["jsonData"]` I used `response.Data` so I don't use another variable. Thanks!